# Creating comma separated character values for each cell in a column for each id using R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have 2 columns ID and Product:

```
ID  Product
A   Clothing
B   Food
A   Food
A   Furniture
C   Food
B   Clothing
```

How can I create a dataframe using R where each ID will have the products as comma separated as below:

```
ID  Product
A   Clothing, Food, Furniture
B   Food, Clothing
C   Food, Clothing
```

Comment: For the 'ID' C, there is no 'Clothing' in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either use one of the group by functions.  With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', we `paste` the elements of 'Product' together.  The `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(Product=toString(Product)), by = ID]
```

---

A similar option with `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(Product= toString(Product))
```

---

Or we can do with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Product~ID, df1, FUN=toString)
#    ID                   Product
#  1  A Clothing, Food, Furniture
#  2  B            Food, Clothing
#  3  C                      Food
```

Comment: Thank you. All 3 ways worked fine but leaving me with another challenge. There are duplicate product values for each ID. How do I get rid of them, see below :                                                                                             ID Product
A Clothing, Clothing Food, Furniture, Furniture
B Food,Food,Food, Clothing
C Food, Clothing, Clothing

Comment: @Madhumita Please check the edited comment with the code.  I think it should solve it.

Comment: I tried unique before posing this comment. It didn't work. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Madhumita Can you update your post with the example.  It is difficult to copy/paste the example from the comment.

Comment: I'll put it as a separate question. Cannot post a question within 90 minutes. You were very helpful. Thanks once again.